# WPF XAML Parse Exception?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, exception

I was working on a WPF application, and it was running fine. I commented out an if check to test something in a utility class, and all of a sudden my program stopped running due to a XAML Parse Exception. The part of the XAML that it points to is the opening tag and to this attribute:

```
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
```

The full tag is this:

```
<Window x:Class="MyApplication.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Topmost="False" KeyUp="KeyUpCheck" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" ResizeMode="NoResize" mc:Ignorable="d" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" d:DesignWidth="441" d:DesignHeight="319">
```

The exact error is this:

> 'The invocation of the constructor on type 'MyApplication.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '4' and line position '291'.

The attribute is what is generated when I resize the form in the viewport. I'm completely clueless as to why it's giving me this error. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to post the entire xaml to find the cause of the exception

Comment: The cause is the attribute I posted. My question is how to fix it.

Comment: The problem is not in the <Window/> tag or in the namespace, sometimes the error will be in the xaml for which the compiler will point to the first tag of the xaml code. Hence it is not possible to find the error with the <Window> tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The invocation of the constructor on type 'MyApplication.MainWindow' ... threw an exception"
Turn on breaking on thrown exceptions and see what exception is being thrown in your constructor.

Comment: Turning on thrown exceptions didn't reveal the issue, but suddenly made the problem go away. More confusion, but the problem is gone. Thanks.